# Get strings between " ---- " from the array

Tags: java, arrays

If I have a string array as follows:

```
String[] name = {"aval", "H ---- ", "Singh", "Sawh", "Gopi", "G ---- ", "parminder", "kaur", "jaspreet", "asneet", " ---- "};
```

And if the user searches for the string "Sawh". I want to show all the strings that's between "H ---- " and "G ---- ". That is the result should display "SinghSawhGopi". I have tried as following but this appears to be wrong. I am able to get the string that is after the "Sawh" correctly but not before from "H ---- " to "Sawh" Someone here have any ideas on how to approach to this?

```
String keywords = "";
int j = 0, k = 0, m = 0, n = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < name.length; i++){
    if(name[i].contains("Sawh")){


     for(j = i+1; !name[j].contains(" ---- "); j++){
          keywords = keywords + name[j];
          k = j;
      }
      for(j = i+1; !name[j].contains(" ---- "); j++){
          keywords = keywords + name[j];
      }

   }
}
System.out.println(keywords);
```

Comment: You can do this in one parse. Can you explain more about what are you trying to achieve so that I can be sure of my suggestion.

Comment: I am able to get in broken pieces but I would like to know if there's any easier way that I don't know of.

Comment: A tip from an experienced programmer - grab a piece of paper and a pen and write down exactly what your program does (in terms of how the variables change at each step) (or you could use a debugger) - this should tell you why your code isn't working. And, after you've done this, you should already have a fair idea of what you need to change to fix it (assuming you've thought through how your program needs to do what you want to do). Also `name[j] + keywords` instead of `keywords + name[j]` might help (in case you get to a point where some of the words are in reverse order).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    String[] name = {"aval", "H ---- ", "Singh", "Sawh", "Gopi", "G ---- ", "parminder", "kaur", "jaspreet", "asneet", " ---- "};
    int length = name.length;
    String query = "Sawh";
    int match_index = -1;
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
        if (name[i] != null && name[i].equals(query)) {
            match_index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    String keywords = "";
    //Match found
    if (match_index != -1) {
        //Forward match.
        for (int i=match_index+1; i<length; i++) {
            if (name[i] == null) {
                continue;
            }
            else if (!name[i].contains(" ---- ")) {
                keywords += name[i];
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
        //Backwards match.
        for (int i=match_index; i>=0; i--) {
            if (name[i] == null) {
                continue;
            }
            else if (!name[i].contains(" ---- ")) {
                keywords = name[i] + keywords;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        //Match not found.
    }
    System.out.println(keywords);
}
```

Lovely little main method I've quickly set up for you. It's not the fastest way to get the required strings, nor is it the best, and it's probably not the cleanest. But it's easy code, lots of small steps and somewhat easy to follow.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple way to do **exactly what you asked**, using some **state**:

```
private static final int STATE_START = 0;
private static final int STATE_FOUND = 1;
private static final int STATE_STOP = 2;

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final String[] name = { "aval", "H ---- ", "Singh", "Sawh", "Gopi", "G ---- ", "parminder", "kaur", "jaspreet", "asneet", " ---- " };
    String keywords = "";

    int state = STATE_START;
    int i = 0;
    while ((state != STATE_STOP) && (i < name.length)) {
        if (name[i].contains(" ---- ")) {
            if (state == STATE_FOUND) {
                state = STATE_STOP;
            } else {
                keywords = "";
            }
        } else {
            keywords += name[i];
            if (name[i].contains("Sawh")) {
                state = STATE_FOUND;
            }
        }

        i++;
    }

    System.out.println(keywords);  // SinghSawhGopi
}
```

**BUT**, maybe you could actually review your data structure... let's assume that you want some `Strings` to be associated with some letters, for example:

- "aval" -> "I"
- "Singh" -> "H"
- "Sawh" -> "H"
- "Gopi" -> "H"
- "parminder" -> "G"

... then I would recommend you to use Google's [Guava Multimaps](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html). The following piece of code would be how to achieve what you're looking for using that data structure:

```
// Create the data (code used only once)
final Multimap<String, String> multimap = HashMultimap.create();
multimap.put("I", "aval");
multimap.put("H", "Singh");
multimap.put("H", "Sawh");
multimap.put("H", "Gopi");
multimap.put("G", "parminder");
multimap.put("G", "kaur");
multimap.put("G", "jaspreet");
multimap.put("G", "asneet");

final Multimap<String, String> inversedMultimap = Multimaps.invertFrom(multimap, HashMultimap.<String, String> create());

// Find the data you're looking for:
System.out.println(multimap.get(inversedMultimap.get("Sawh").iterator().next()));
// Output: [Singh,Sawh, Gopi]

// Or, if you really need the output you described in your question:
String keywords = "";
for (final String keyword : multimap.get(inversedMultimap.get("Sawh").iterator().next())) {
    keywords += keyword;
}

System.out.println(keywords);  // SinghSawhGopi
```

Cheers :)